# What is this extra interrogation in null coalescence operator

Tags: c#, resharper, ternary-operator, c#-6.0, null-coalescing-operator

I have this conditional:

```
if (dr_dados["DAT_SAIDA"] != null)
    {
        txtDataSaida.Text = "";
    }
    else
    {
        txtDataSaida.Text = dr_dados["DAT_SAIDA"].ToString();
    }
```

I'm using Jetbrain's ReSharper and it told me I could transform into a ternary operation.

So, it became this:

```
txtDataSaida.Text = (dr_dados["DAT_SAIDA"] != null) ? dr_dados["DAT_SAIDA"].ToString() : "";
```

But then it told me I could transform into a null coalescence operation, and it gave me this:

```
txtDataSaida.Text = dr_dados["DAT_SAIDA"]?.ToString() ?? "";
```

I sort of know what the null coalescence operation does, but there was something different, something I haven't seen before and I'd like to know what it is.

This extra interrogation right here:

```
                                         v
txtDataSaida.Text = dr_dados["DAT_SAIDA"]?.ToString() ?? "";
```

What does it do/mean?

Comment: I didn't know which term to use for the symbol because I really don't know what it means, so I couldn't search anything on it. If there is another question in SO asking about this, mark as a duplicate :)

Comment: [C# 6.0 Features](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6). Get acquainted with them because you will see more and more.

Comment: Oh crap, this is a new feature. I'm not sure if our production server has C# 6.0. Thanks for the information

Comment: C# 6 is the compiler, so if R# suggested it then you can use it.

Comment: I know but Resharper is installed only in my development envrionment, I'm not sure if the production server is up-to-date. But I believe it is.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes It's irrelevant what's on the production sever, all that matters is whether or not the machine compiling the code has the proper version.  If you have a build server, or other developers using the code, then all of those machines need to be up to date, but the machines all running the code don't care what version of C# compiled the program.

Comment: Ah yeah I forgot about that. The thing that matters would be only the .net version, the compiler is the one responsible for the code. Well I checked with the server manager and he told me that both dev and production servers are always paired with the same versions of everything used in the development process =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a Null-Conditional Operator.

It is used to check for null before actually performing the member access. If the member you are going to access is in fact `null`, then no exception will be thrown, but rather a `null` value will be returned.

Comment: Ohh that's cool! Well you were fast so I'll check this as the accepted answer. Try adding more explanation and examples for any potential future viewers, please ;)

Comment: Not to steal any thunder from Matias, but [here's some examples on SO's Documentation site.](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/41/null-conditional-operators/173/null-conditional-operator)